# Looking for books on How the limbic system works and it role in non-verbal behavior

Tags: neuroscience, brain, behaviour

This is my first post. I just read and I'm currently studying a book called "How everybody works" as a guide to understanding nonverbal behaviors.

After I'm done studying it and while I experiment with its claims; I'm looking to understand more of how the limbic system works and its role in human emotions.

The book's premise is that the limbic system makes us react to certain situations in such ways that nonverbal behavior is expressed; therefore by understanding the limbic system and nonverbal behavior we can ascertain a person's reaction to outside stimuli and gain insight.

If anyone could provide recommendations on books about the Limbic system 
that are up to date with current finds or any other books that relate to the topics above I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you are still looking, but I have two recommendations for you.

1. **"Limbic systems for emotion and for memory, but no single limbic system"** is a really long, but really great article on the topic.  You can find that online here:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010945213003110?via%3Dihub
2. It's been a while since I've read this one, but the book ***Synaptic Self:  How Our Brains Become Who We Are*** is a good read on this subject.  It's about the brain as a whole, but focuses a lot on the limbic system and amygdala (it's author, Joseph LeDoux, did much of the pioneering work on the amygdala).  It is from 1996, so the science isn't super up to date, but I still think it's a good read if you're just curious about the brain and limbic system.